# Let authenticated user write to his node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rules, firebase-authentication

I guess I have a really basic question but because of the bad tutorial and strange results I am really stuck with this problem.
So I followed the tutorial on how to use Firebase user authentication and database with Android from here https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio#adding_and_removing_to-do_items_from_the_mobile_app. Now I just want to let users write to their own node in my database. My data should look like this:

```
shoppinglistplusplus-ss
    --> users
        --> several nodes with Firebase Uids.
```

My rules for this database are as follows:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
            }
        }
    }
}.
```

Right now the database is completly empty. I am using Facebook login so I pass the access token of Facebook to Firebase. Within my Android application I try to write to it using this code:

```
AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        new Firebase("https://shoppinglistplusplus-ss.firebaseio.com")
                            .child("users")
                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .setValue("bub bub bub");
                    }
                }
            });.
```

So the whole code is running. Unfortunately I do net see any data coming up in my database. Now here comes the strange part. If I use the simulator to validate my rules I get a positive feedback. Also when I switch the database rules to public I see the data coming up.

Also I have seen another approach on writing to the database here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/. Anyway using this gives me an exception because I do not know how to set my Firebase url.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");.
```

What am I doing wrong ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you included `google-services.json` in your project app folder?

Comment: Yes I did. I guess without it I could not even write to the database even if it is public, could I ? :( Could there may be any information missing in that file ?

Comment: What about console? Did you enabled FB authentication ?

Comment: You say _"using this gives me an exception because I do not know how to set my Firebase url"_. When using the 9.0.x version of Firebase, the URL is in the `google-services.json` you (presumably) created at the Firebase Console and downloaded into your project.  What's the exception?

Comment: hey guys ... thanks for your suggestions ... it seems that a broken google-services.json file was the reason. i started all over again, created a new project in firebase and refreshed the file. now it seems to work with the second approach (using FirebaseDatabase). thank you guys.